# Ryan Fait's CSS sticky footer not working

Tags: html, css

```css
* {margin: 0;}

html, body {height: 100%;}

.wrapper {
     min-height: 100%;
     height: auto !important;
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0 auto -4em;
}

.footer, .push {height: 4em; }

.footer {background-color: red;}
}
```

```html
    
    <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
       <p>Your website content here.</p>
        <div class="push"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>Copyright (c) 2008</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

I have the similar structure and code on my website: http://test.tattech.ru/company/ but it doesn't work there.

What am I not seeing?

EDIT: So I had another div wrapping `wrapper` and adding `height:100%` as pointed out by [karlisup](https://stackoverflow.com/users/492457/karlisup) to it solved the problem

Comment: works for me in firefox & chrome.

Comment: You set html, body to 100%, but forgot another wrapper with class .site to set 100%

Comment: @karlisup Yes, it helped. Thanks a lot.